# Templating JavaScript and CSS files with TAL

Tags: template-engine, zope, zpt

Is it possible to template `JavaScript` or `CSS` files with `TAL`?

(or maybe there is some other templating mechanism in `Zope` exists)

e.g. templated `CSS` file will be something like that:

```css
#button {
  background-color: <%= buttonColor %>;
  background-image: <%= buttonImage %>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zope2, use [DTML](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/DTML.html).  TAL/ZPT is only appropriate for HTML/XML/SGMLish markups.

If you are using [browser views](http://developer.plone.org/views/browserviews.html), you can also choose to use any Python-based template system, should you be willing to take care of rendering the template in your view's `index()` (or `__call__()`) method.